firebase/authentication error-Cross origin redirect sign-in on Google Chrome M115+ is no longer supported, and will stop working on June 24, 2024
i am building an webapp in react.js and using firebase for login by email/password method, but this error will not let me store the userid/password.mostly it is related to CORS issue.
this is my firebase configure code.
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional, 

HIDED the PERSONAL ID AND DATA

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDw6105zrb-IhlcZxDa****************",
  authDomain: "netlfix-gpt******.web.app",
  projectId: "netlfix-gpt******",
  storageBucket: "netlfix-gpt*******.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "9065506*******",
  appId: "1:906550651177:web:***************",
  measurementId: "G-HQ********"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

export const auth= getAuth();


Firebase.json file code
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}


Firebaserc file Code:
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "netlfix-gpt-*****"
  }
}

this is the firebase file codes.
i have tried other solution given on youtube,stackoverflow,but not so many answers,also readed firebase documentation,but not able to understand properly.
Here it is.DOCUMENTATION
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices?hl=en&authuser=0
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "<api-key>",
  authDomain: "<the-domain-that-serves-your-app>",
  databaseURL: "<database-url>",
  projectId: "<project-id>",
  appId: "<app-id>"
};

this is error thrown
Cross origin redirect sign-in on Google Chrome M115+ is no longer supported, and will stop working on June 24, 2024.
Migrate to an alternative solution before June 24, 2024
End-users can continue to sign in to your app until June 24, 2024
This is already required on Firefox 109+ and Safari 16.1+
kindly help,stuck from 2 weeks.

This error should appear only if you are using signInWithRedirect or something similar. In this case you can switch to using signInWithPopup
Sign in with email and password shouldn't be causing this to appear. Make sure you enabled email / password auth method - as described here

i have tried the email/password method. as you saying try signInWithPopup,but not able to understand or implement in my code,tried changing the code, but i guess i am doing it in wrong way.
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email.current.value,password.current.value)   .then((userCredential) => {     // Signed up      const user = userCredential.user;     console.log(user);     // ...   })   .catch((error) => {     const errorCode = error.code;     const errorMessage = error.message;     setErrorMessage(errorCode +"-"+ errorMessage);     // ..   }); 

@VineetRaj What is the problem you are facing now? Do you still get the CORS error?
For email / password user you need to register the user first with UserWithEmailAndPassword method. This will create the user in your firebase auth and the user will be logged in. Next time you want to  log in you need to use signInWithEmailAndPasswordmethod.
If you want to login with a different provider (like Facebook or Google) you can use signInWithPopup(auth, provider). This will create user on the first login, and then you will be able to use this provider to login to your app.

actualy i am following a course,there when he enter the detail in a signin form,the data gets stored on firebase,but in my case it is not working.i can see the data on console,but not on my authentication user data.
